# What is the correct graphql response if a requested child object does not exist?

Tags: graphql

What shall the graphql server return if a child object does not exist?

Example schema:

```
type Person {
  name: String!
  address: Address
}

type Address {
  street: String
  city: String
}
```

On the server, there is a Person, but no Address exist on that person.
The fact that the address is missing is not an error, it is just not yet set.

Then I have this query:

```
query Person(name: "Otto") {
    name
    address {
        street
        city
    }
}
```

What is the correct response?
I can think of two alternatives:

Alt 1:

```json
{
    "data": {
        "person": {
            "name": "Otto",
            "address": null
            "__typename": "Person"
        }
    }
}
```

Alt 2:

```json
{
    "data": {
        "person": {
            "name": "Otto",
            "address": {
                "street": null,
                "city": null
                "__typename": "Address"
            }
            "__typename": "Person"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In my opinion the correct answer is highly opinion based. So no one can choose (for you) what the correct alternative is, it will be a choice that you have to make.

Comment: I thought the idea with graphql was to avoid such ambiguity.

Comment: There is no ambiguity, because alternative1 is different from alternative2 ?

Comment: @Luuk - if there are two possible correct answers then that is the very definition of *ambiguity*. Fortunately the spec only allows one.

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer is (1) - `null` will be returned for the parent object; the entire branch of the JSON tree is trimmed at the first point where a nullable object is null. If in your case `address` was not nullable then you would get an error.

[specification](https://spec.graphql.org/June2018/#sec-Type-System.Non-Null)

If (2) was the correct answer then the field resolvers for the `address` type would each have to execute to return a value but their parents would all be null. Furthermore if `address` nested further types they would have to execute as well and return more nested null values and so on. Every resolver would have to test for a null parent.